# Token rotation refresh implementation how to persist token?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, access-token, refresh-token

I have implemented all of the code to support token rotation/ refresh with one last hitch. How are we supposed to persist the token on the frontend to make authenticated backend calls beyond our login?

My Current workflow goes as follows:

1. User logs in with email and password and is returned the refresh token and the access token in an HTTP-only secure cookie.
2. A MongoDB (body) document along with the refresh Token and Access Token in **HTTP-only**, **secure** **cookies** is returned with the response.

Now moving on from here how can we persist using these cookies? Especially since we cannot access these. I am using HTTP-only cookies as that is what is recommended as it is most secure but I am struggling to see how it is possible with only HTTP cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this. HTTP cookies persist by default. They were not persisting in my case as I had the secure property set to true and I was not over an https connection.